# Fundamental calculus Theorem: how it works with a radial function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $N\geq 1, 1<p<N$ and $u\in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a radial function. Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha> 1-N$. Thus, direct computations give
$$
\frac{d}{dr}(|u(r)|^p r^{\alpha +N-1})\geq p\, r^{\alpha +N-1} |u|^{p-2} u\frac{du}{dr}.
$$
I found written in my lecture notes that the above estimate it implies, if $r>0$, that
$$|u|^p r^{\alpha +N-1}\leq p\int_r^{+\infty} s^{\alpha +N-1} |u|^{p-1} |u^{\prime}(s)| ds.$$

My question is: why? It seems to me that something related to fundamental theorem of calculus is used, but I don't understand how to justify the latest inequality.

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By FTC and the given amount of decay at infinity, $|u|^p r^{\alpha+N-1}=-\int_r^\infty \frac{d}{ds} \left ( |u(s)|^p s^{\alpha+N-1} \right ) \, ds$ then apply the given inequality (taking absolute values first if need be).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand why $s^{\alpha+N-1}\geq r^{\alpha+N-1}$ and not just equality. Moreover, I don't understand where the first inequality comes into play (to me, it seems a little bit in contrast with the second one).

Comment: @User1010 $s$ is the variable of integration, but it takes values in $[r,\infty)$, so $s \geq r$ and then since $\alpha+N-1>0$ you have $s^{\alpha+N-1} \geq r^{\alpha+N-1}$. But I see what the rest of the point was now.

Comment: @User1010 Is it clear now?

Comment: perfectly clear, thank you!